# How to play high fps videos in Android

Tags: android, video, android-videoview

I want to play videos which has higher frames per second. Eg: 90fps,120fps
When I use a video view to play them, it's not playing smoothly. Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Max framerate on Android is 60FPS.